# VSCode colour highlighted area

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I am in a function or in a segment of a loop this area is colored. It's annoying me.
How to get rid out of it? Disabled some extension, doesn't fix that.[highlighted area, I want to not get this highligting feature.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdBpF.png)

I have disabled some color and auto tag extensions. Doesn't get help.

Comment: before you ask such questions try out with a clean VSC Insiders, only the needed language extension, like ms-python or ms-cpp, ..... If effect is gone it is due to some extension you have installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it happened for an extension named "Indented Block highlight."
After disabling the extension, that area highlighting is gone away.